# Mixer line in max voltage

Tags: voltage, amplifier, mixer

I have built a tube amplifier and modded it with a line out for headphones based on [this](https://diyaudioheaven.wordpress.com/tutorials/power-amp-adapter/) article.

I measured the output voltage on the artificial "line out" is peaking around 4-5V. 
As a reference I also tested what my mp3 player delivers and that is around 500 mV

is it safe to introduce 5 V to my mixer (Behringer Xenyx 502) line in?

the manual specifies that the line ins are "designed to handle typical line level signals". 
based on [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76010/what-is-the-typical-max-voltage-for-sound-card-line-in) post typical is around 300mV, however it may peak to 3 V

I might have answered my own qustion, but a confirmation would be nice

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fine. If it's too loud, just turn down the gain in the mixer.

I don't know about the Behringer<sup>1</sup> specifically, but most professional audio gear uses ±15 V power rails on its line input and line output circuits, because peak signal levels can readily reach ±12 V or more.

<sup>1</sup> The [manual](https://static.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/61870.pdf) states that it can handle +22 dBu, which would be a signal that reaches ±13.8 V peaks. (0 dBu is 0.775 Vrms, multiply this by 10<sup>22/20</sup> and then by √2 to convert from RMS to peak for a sine wave.)