# earphone microphone out put voltage range

Tags: microphone

I want to send a signal through the 3.5mm jack(microphone port) to an android mobile and process the signal using android mobile application I created.

But I don't know the voltage range the microphone port can sustain. Please help me.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76010/what-is-the-typical-max-voltage-for-sound-card-line-in

Comment: @LosFrijoles Your link is useful but does not really answer their question.

Comment: Well RaviSri, this question is impossible to answer. *Which* Android phone? Have you tried measuring voltage coming out of the port? There are several types of microphones; some require power and some do not. Voltage being present can help determine which type is expected, and thus how to approach a solution. That said, many devices employ a mux for the audio jack today because there are several types of incompatible plugs. I'd read up on electret microphones too, to understand how those work and why voltage is needed. So no, there is no easy answer for this.